# MySQL multiple updates on the same table time out

Tags: java, mysql, timeout

I'm running an MMORPG-server written in Java with a MySQL database. For a few months it has run quite well, but as we grew more popular and the database got bigger, we started to get problems. The queries were all run in the same threads that also processed packets (yes, it was designed quite poorly), which caused major lags - we counterfeited this by implementing a save-worker which periodically saves characters that haven't been saved for 10 minutes in 5 threads. Additionally, five other threads process database queries that need instant processing during gameplay.

Our problem is that updates that access the table that contains general information about the characters take a long time for some reason and then timeout.

Processlist: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2BIL.png

The `characters` updates contain about 30 more fields and end with WHERE id = *?*.

Layouts of the tables that appear in the processlist:

```
TABLE `characters` ( -- Contains about 300.000 rows
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `accountid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `world` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `exp` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `str` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dex` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `luk` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `int` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
...
  `job` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `accountid` (`accountid`),
  KEY `ranking1` (`level`,`exp`),
  KEY `ranking2` (`job`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

TABLE `items` ( -- contains 34 million rows
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `inventoryType` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `characterId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `accountId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `itemId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_items_1` (`characterId`),
  KEY `FK_items_2` (`accountId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_items_1` FOREIGN KEY (`characterId`) REFERENCES `characters` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_items_2` FOREIGN KEY (`accountId`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

TABLE `wishlists` ( -- contains ~75.000 rows
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `characterId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `serialNumber` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_wishlists_1` (`characterId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_wishlists_1` FOREIGN KEY (`characterId`) REFERENCES `characters` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

It's a dedicated server running WS2008 R2, MySQL 5.5.22 and Java 7. Java connects via JDBC (MySQL connector 5.1.18) to the database and autoCommit is set to false for these queries, isloation is TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED. Server has 32 GB RAM, 24 of which is used for Java, the rest is available for MySQL. 
Some settings:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8G
innodb_log_file_size=1024M
innodb_thread_concurrency=10
```

What could be the cause of that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using locks correctly when you access the table?  I don't know your access setup, but sounds like you might be getting read/write starvation.

Comment: Nope, we aren't using locks anywhere. Can you explain how we would go about adding them? The method that saves characters first updates the `characters` table and then updates all other tables (which takes some time depending on database load), finally it commits the data.